# How to connect Samsung galaxy S9 plus to internet while phone is locked and notification bar is also locked and I have forgotten pattern lock

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I have forgotten my phone's pattern lock now in order to unlock it there is one option I know is by using Samsung account I can unlock it but unfortunately my phone's notification bar is locked and phone's ADB debugging is also off, so how can I make my phone online. I don't want to hard reset as it will erase my data in the phone so please if anyone know how to connect a locked phone to internet please tell me and also let me know if you know how to break pattern lock without losing data. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

insert sim card into another phone and disable SIM PIN completely. now insert sim card back into locked phone it will connect to mobile data automatically without asking for PIN. finally login to [find my mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) on pc and remote unlock phone